# constrain generic type to inherit a generic type in f#

Tags: f#

```
let mapTuple f (a,b) = (f a, f b)
```

I'm trying to create a function that applies a function `f` to both items in a tuple and returns the result as a tuple. F# type inference says that `mapTuple` returns a `'b*'b` tuple. It also assumes that `a` and `b` are of the same type.

I want to be able to pass two different types as parameters. You would think that wouldn't work because they both have to be passed as parameters to `f`. So I thought if they inherited from the same base class, it might work.

Here is a less generic function for what I am trying to accomplish.

```
let mapTuple (f:Map<_,_> -> Map<'a,'b>) (a:Map<int,double>,b:Map<double, int>) = (f a, f b)
```

However, it gives a type mismatch error.

How do I do it?  Is what I am trying to accomplish even possible in F#?

Comment: I don't see a nice way to have it work as you want it (without forfeiting type information by boxing/unboxing the maps). A nice solution in a vacuum would be wrapping your two map types with a union, so that `f` has a single concrete type to work with, but whether it's a good idea depends on your problem.

Comment: That would work, but any since this function is mainly for convenience, having to deal with a union would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of stating the obvious, a good enough solution might be to have a `mapTuple` that takes two functions instead of one:

```
let mapTuple fa fb (a, b) = (fa a, fb b)
```

If your original `f` is generic, passing it as `fa` and `fb` will give you two concrete instantiations of the function with the types you're looking for. At worst, you just need to pass the same function twice when `a` and `b` are of the same type.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that.  Unfortunately, I was planning to convert the function to an operator, which doesn't quite work with this solution

Answer (score 6):

Gustavo is mostly right; what you're asking for requires higher-rank types.  However,

1. .NET (and by extension F#) does support (an encoding of) higher-rank types.
2. Even in Haskell, which supports a "nice" way of expressing such types (once you've enabled the right extension), they wouldn't be inferred for your example.

Digging into point 2 may be valuable: given `map f a b = (f a, f b)`, why doesn't Haskell infer a more general type than `map :: (t1 -> t) -> t1 -> t1 -> (t, t)`?  The reason is that once you include higher-rank types, it's not typically possible to infer a single "most general" type for a given expression.  Indeed, there are many possible higher-rank signatures for `map` given its simple definition above:

1. `map :: (forall t. t -> t) -> x -> y -> (x, y)`
2. `map :: (forall t. t -> z) -> x -> y -> (z, z)`
3. `map :: (forall t. t -> [t]) -> x -> y -> ([x], [y])`

(plus infinitely many more).  But note that these are all incompatible with each other (none is more general than another).  Given the first one you can call `map id 1 'c'`, given the second one you can call `map (\_ -> 1) 1 'c'`, and given the third one you can call `map (\x -> [x]) 1 'c'`, but those arguments are *only* valid with each of those types, not with the other ones.

So even in Haskell you need to specify the particular polymorphic signature you want to use - this may be a bit of a surprise if you're coming from a more dynamic language.  In Haskell, this is relatively clean (the syntax is what I've used above).  However, in F# you'll have to jump through an additional hoop: there's no clean syntax for a "forall" type, so you'll have to create an additional nominal type instead.  For example, to encode the first type above in F# I'd write something like this:

```
type Mapping = abstract Apply : 'a -> 'a

let map (m:Mapping) (a, b) = m.Apply a, m.Apply b

let x, y = map { new Mapping with member this.Apply x = x } (1, "test")
```

Note that in contrast to Gustavo's suggestion, you can define the first argument to `map` as an expression (rather than forcing it to be a member of some separate type).  On the other hand, there's clearly a lot more boilerplate than would be ideal...

Comment: I think it would be nice to have in Haskell an extension that allows you to write a generic map like the one in my sample code but directly with functions. The signature should be not restricted at all. In this example it would be mapTuple :: (t1 -> t2) -> (a1, b1) -> (a2, b2) then at the point the function is called the type inference may go further.

Answer (score 4):

This problem has to do with [rank-n types](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Rank-N_types) which are supported in Haskell (through extensions) but not in .NET type system.

One way I found to workaround this limitation is to pass a type with a single method instead of a function and then define an inline *map* function with static constraints, for example let's suppose I have some generic functions: `toString` and `toOption` and I want to be able to map them to a tuple of different types:

```
type ToString = ToString with static member inline ($) (ToString, x) = string x
type ToOption = ToOption with static member        ($) (ToOption, x) = Some x

let inline mapTuple f (x, y) = (f $ x, f $ y)

let tuple1 = mapTuple ToString (true, 42)
let tuple2 = mapTuple ToOption (true, 42)

// val tuple1 : string * string = ("True", "42")
// val tuple2 : bool option * int option = (Some true, Some 42)
```

`ToString` will return the same type but operating with arbitrary types. `ToOption` will return two Generics of different types.

By using a binary operator type inference creates the static constraints for you and I use `$` because in Haskell it means *apply* so a nice detail is that for haskellers `f $ x` reads already *apply x to f*.

Comment: It's not very convenient.  For every function I would want to use mapTuple for, I would have to create a whole new type.

Comment: Of course, I agree. Much more convenient would be to have Rank-n types and pass functions directly but that's not possible at the moment and I don't think they will implement it in the near future.